# MySQL connection error with NodeJS on Heroku (works in Dev)

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

My application works correctly in Localhost with following connection details:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
host: "gatorxxxx.hostgator.com",
user: "ermaulik_chdb",
password: "<password>",
database: "ermaulik_chdb",
port: <port>
})

mysqlConnection.connect((err) => {
if(!err) {
console.log("Connection")
} else {
console.log(err)
}
});
```

But, it doesn't work when I host this application on Heroku and throws following exception.

Just to give more context, my database in hosted in cpanel of hostgator.

```
2020-05-23T16:47:32.542824+00:00 app[web.1]: server is running on port: 54806
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812651+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'ermaulik_chdb'@'ec2-3-84-45-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812658+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812659+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:123:18)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812659+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812660+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Parser._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812661+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Parser.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812661+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812662+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812662+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812662+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812663+00:00 app[web.1]:     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812663+00:00 app[web.1]:     --------------------
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812664+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812664+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812665+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812665+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/connection.js:11:17)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812666+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812666+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812666+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812667+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812667+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812667+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18) {
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812668+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812668+00:00 app[web.1]:   errno: 1045,
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812669+00:00 app[web.1]:   sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'ermaulik_chdb'@'ec2-3-84-45-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (using password: YES)",
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812669+00:00 app[web.1]:   sqlState: '28000',
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812669+00:00 app[web.1]:   fatal: true
2020-05-23T16:47:32.812670+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'ermaulik_chdb'@'ec2-3-84-45-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
```

you got an Error. because your MySQL database connection is Not Established. 
Firstly, please check the Installed LAMP, Nodejs Acc. to your Code version supported. in the Heroku server. properly.

In the second step, check the MYSQL DB GRANT PRIVILEGES.

```
 SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
```

the Third one is to Make sure your Nodejs Code & MySql DB
 in the same server. If not you need to allow permission a server to connect OutSide the server.

and make sure the host, username, password, HOST all things are correct. I hope these things help you resolve a problem. thanks :)